# Error when using UDL file

Tags: data-access

I got a problem when I using UDL file on a Windows XP pc. It shows error messeage "provider cannot be found. ensure that the provider has been installed properly".

I've search some article online, most of them mentioned that it occured on X64 OS, but my Windows XP is 32bit and patched SP3.

I just try to open the UDL file but it show the error. I'm using this UDL to get external data from a SQL Server database in a xlsx file.

Answer (score 0):

UDL created on Win 7 can't opened on Win XP, strange thing.